# listview no data exists for the selected row/column c# InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, listview, exception, selectedindexchanged

I am 100% sure my listview has data. My program will get the ID from the column 0 of my listview, connects to the database, and using the ID as my reference will get the data from my database and display it to my textboxes/comboboxes. SO when I click an item from my listview, an exception appears and all of my textboxes as well as my comboboxes are empty. I am new to c# and programming, any help will be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string button = null;
        private string carID;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textDateReg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lvRefresh();
        }

        private void lvRefresh()
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\genesis\\Documents\\Database2.accdb";
            con.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ID, PlateNo from Cars", con);
            OleDbDataReader cmdrdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (cmdrdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (cmdrdr.Read())

                {
                    ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(cmdrdr["ID"].ToString());
                    list.SubItems.Add(cmdrdr["PlateNo"].ToString());
                    listView1.Items.Add(list);
                }
            }

            con.Close();
            cmdrdr.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button = "new";
            buttonSub.Enabled = true;
            panel1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void textBox7_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox7.Text = null;
        }

        private void buttonSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (button)
            {
                case "new":

                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Register?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string Adrs = this.textADRS.Text;
                        string Fname = this.textFN.Text;
                        string Mname = this.textMN.Text;
                        string Lname = this.textLN.Text;
                        string Age = this.textAGE.Text;
                        string RegDate = this.textDateReg.Text;
                        string Gender = comboGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        string Phone = this.textPHONE.Text;
                        string Color = this.textColor.Text;
                        string Type = this.comboType.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        string Brand = this.textBrand.Text;
                        string Model = this.textModel.Text;
                        string PlateNo = this.textPlateNo.Text;

                        try
                        {
                            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\genesis\\Documents\\Database2.accdb";
                            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into Drivers (FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Address,Age,PhoneNo,Gender,RegDate) Values (@FirstName,@MidName,@LastName,@Address,@Age,@Phone,@Gender,@RegDate)", con);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FirstName", Fname));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@MidName", Mname));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LastName", Lname));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Address", Adrs));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Age", Age));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Phone", Phone));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Gender", Gender));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@RegDate", RegDate));
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            cmd.Dispose();
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into Cars(Color, Brand, Model, Type, PlateNo) Values(@Color, @Brand, @Model, @Type, @PlateNo)", con);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Color", Color));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Brand", Brand));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Model", Model));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Type", Type));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PlateNo", PlateNo));
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            cmd.Dispose();

                            MessageBox.Show("Record Submitted", "Nice!");

                            lvRefresh(); //refresh listview
                        }
                        catch (Exception es)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case "del":

                    dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Register?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string Adrs = this.textADRS.Text;
                        string Fname = this.textFN.Text;
                        string Mname = this.textMN.Text;
                        string Lname = this.textLN.Text;
                        string Age = this.textAGE.Text;
                        string RegDate = this.textDateReg.Text;
                        string Gender = comboGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        string Phone = this.textPHONE.Text;
                        string Color = this.textColor.Text;
                        string Type = this.comboType.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        string Brand = this.textBrand.Text;
                        string Model = this.textModel.Text;
                        string PlateNo = this.textPlateNo.Text;

                        try
                        {
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case "edit":
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Enabled = true;//panel that contains my textboxes/comboboxes
            buttonDel.Enabled = true;
            try
            {
                ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
                carID = item.Text;

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\genesis\\Documents\\Database2.accdb";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Drivers where ID = @ID", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", carID);
                OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    textFN.Text = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    textMN.Text = rdr["MiddleName"].ToString();
                    textLN.Text = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                    textADRS.Text = rdr["Address"].ToString();
                    textPHONE.Text = rdr["PhoneNo"].ToString();
                    textDateReg.Text = rdr["RegDate"].ToString();
                    textAGE.Text = rdr["Age"].ToString();
                    comboGender.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString();

                    if (!rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        rdr.Close();
                        cmd.Dispose();

                        OleDbCommand cmdc = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Cars where ID = @ID", con);
                        cmdc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", carID);
                        OleDbDataReader rdrc = cmdc.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdrc.HasRows)
                        {
                            textColor.Text = rdr["Color"].ToString();
                            comboType.Text = rdr["Type"].ToString();
                            textBrand.Text = rdr["Brand"].ToString();
                            textModel.Text = rdr["Model"].ToString();
                            textPlateNo.Text = rdr["PlateNo"].ToString();
                        }
                        rdrc.Close();
                        cmdc.Dispose();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the exception to the question

Comment: there you go, I have edited my question